# Insert a certain date format into MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

A very simple Insert statement with a topic and a date I would like to insert the date as a certain format "MM/DD/YY" Don't know if it's possible or not?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Topic (Topic,date) VALUES ('$Topic',NOW())";
```

Comment: If the datatype of your `date` column in the `Topic` table is `DATE`, you're good to go. What you have will work fine. If you need to return a string from the `date` column in a particular format, use the **`DATE_FORMAT`** function. MySQL provides an inverse function,  to create a **`DATE`** (or `DATETIME`) from a string, that function is appropriately named **`STR_TO_DATE`**. If the datatype of the column `date` is something *other* than `DATE`, how do I say this politely, you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible using just `NOW()`. That format is not the standard date format for MySQL so you have to store it as a string. But that is a bad idea because you can use any of MySQL's date functions without first converting back into a valid date which is tedious.

Just store your dates in the `date` data type and then when you want to retrieve them use [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to transform them into MM/DD/YY format.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, "%m/%d/%y") as date FROM ....
-- date is now in MM/DD/YY format
```

Comment: Already got it down. Just had to dig more into the PHP part of it.Found This is how I'm setting the date with PHP:
    $date_added=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
And this is how I'm inserting it in the table:
    INSERT INTO MyTable(date_added) VALUES('$date_added')";

Comment: Actually PHP shouldn't even come into play here.

Comment: You can use the PHP and convert and insert the date but yes it would be easier to know how to insert it just using the MySQL query but this added flexibility as well and are going to use it Thanks @John Conde

Comment: Better Edit! Used that instead. Thank you very much Sir! @John Conde